# How to create 2 instances using factorymethod

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factories

I am trying to write a test for my rails application using rspec, I basically want to create two instances

1)a user with counter value 0

2)a user with counter value 5 or more

Here is my factory user code

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "user#{n}@abc.com" }
    name 'rishabh agarwal'
    password '12345678'
    counter 0
  end
end
```

In user_controller_spec file I have written

```
context 'get#redeem' do
  it 'should not redeem the account for points lesser than 5' do
    get :redeem, format: :json,params:{:id=>dummyUser.id}
    expect(JSON.parse(response.body)["message"]).to eq("You cannot redeem your points")
   end

  it 'should redeem the account if points are greater than or equal to 5' do                                       
    get :redeem, format: :json,params:{:id=>dummyUser.id}
    json=JSON.parse(response.body)
    expect(JSON.parse(response.body)["counter"]).to eq(5)
  end
end
```

While I have used `let!` to create instance 
           `let!(:dummyUser){create :user}`

Answer (score 1):

This is how I'd structure your tests:

```
context "get#redeem" do
  before { get :redeem, format: :json, params: { id: user.id } }

  context 'when the user has more than or 5 points' do
    let(:user) { create(:user, counter: 5) }

    it 'redeems the account' do
      json = JSON.parse(response.body)
      expect(json["counter"]).to eq 5
      expect(response.status).to eq 200
    end
  end

  context 'when the user has less than 5 points' do
    let(:user) { create(:user, counter: 4) }

    it 'does not redeem the account' do
      json = JSON.parse(response.body)
      expect(json["message"]).to eq "You cannot redeem your points"
      expect(response.status).to eq 403
    end
  end
end
```

Few notes:

- Not sure about the 403 response code, you might wish to use a different one.
- Consider extracting a method called `json_response` for your tests that will look something like this:

```
def json_response
  @json_response ||= JSON.parse(response.body)
end
```

Comment: I have a question ... If you are creating instance inside context 'when the user has more than or 5 points' do then from where are you accessing user.id in before

Comment: It has to do with when `before` and `let` are evaluated. In this case the `before` block is run just before a single test defined by `it` is run and the variables defined by `let` are already accessible.

Comment: Personally, I'm not a fan of removing the main action from test bodies. But this is still good advice.

Answer (score 0):

Found a better way .... Just initialize the counter variable with 0 in factory and while using context for more then 5 change the value of counter 
dummyUser.counter=5
dummyUser.save 
this will change the value to 5 and which can be used by the test case.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply pass attributes in the create method

```
create(:user, counter: 5)
```