# how to access let'd variables in a before(:each) hook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am refactoring some specs we have and am trying to dry-up some login code in our specs.

I have the following:

```
RSpec.describe AdSourcesController, :type => :controller do

  let!(:user) { FactoryBot.create(:user, user_role: "Publisher Admin") }
  let!(:ad_source) { FactoryBot.create(:ad_source) }

  describe "GET #update custom_vast_tag" do
    before(:all) do
      login_user user, ad_source.company # this is the issue, can't access user or ad_source
    end

    it "with a pre-existing creative" do
      # this is what we are moving
      # login_user user, ad_source.company  
      ...
    end
```

I understand that I cannot access user or ad_source from within a before hook and just in an `it` example. How would I access these variable as a common share across multiple examples?

Comment: It's totally fine to use `let`s in `before(:each)` hooks. You have a `before(:all)` hook which is problematic. Honestly, I'd think whether you should not be using a `before` hook (defaults to `before(:each)`).

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej so I don't want to be using `let` s in my before hook. I'd just like to login my user before a bunch of specs to reduce code duplication. What would you propose instead of a before?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself clear. You don't define `let` inside the hooks, but you can access them inside a `before(:each)` hook. Title of your question speaks of `before(:each)` hooks, your code shows `before(:all)` hook. If you change your hook to `before`, you will be able to use objects defined by `let`s`.

Comment: To be clear, you can't use `let` with `before(:all)`, you can use them with `before(:each)`, see an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53293719/how-to-create-2-instances-using-factorymethod/53293883#53293883) I made yesterday.